# How can I make a div cover the whole width of the page, but not altering the content inside?

Tags: css

How can I make a div cover the whole width of the page, but not altering the content inside? I already tried

```
#maindiv{
margin-right:-100px;
margin-left:-100px;
}
```

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: *"but not altering the content inside"* - What does that mean? The CSS you are showing has nothing to do with your question. Please rephrase.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is to make use of **[`position: fixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Fixed_positioning)**, while also setting a value of `0` for the `top`, `left`, `right` and `bottom` properties:

```css
#full {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div id="full">Text</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)